# Is an Array Index content stored in one memory address?

Tags: c, memory

Assume in C we have the following array of one item:

```
int a[] = {2000};
```

`2000` in binary would be:

```
11111010000
```

If each memory address can hold 1 byte (8 bits) of data, then howcome
in some tutorials, it is mentioned that each array index is stored in one memory address? it's not possible since 2000 has 11 bits and needs at least 2 memory addresses to be stored.

My second question is, if it is stored in 2 (or more) memory addresses, how does the CPU know when to stop reading bits of the memory addresses? how does it know it has reached the end of the variable `a` above?

Comment: A decimal number of `2000` fit's just fine with an `int`, every value in that array may contain at least data of `sizeof(int)` bytes data. What are you asking about?

Comment: how is `2000` stored in memory?

Comment: You seem to have some serious misconceptions about the memory layout of arrays.

Comment: i might. but how is 2000 stored in memory?
| 11111010 | 000 ?
Assuming each`| |` is a memory address

Comment: An `int` probably covers a minimum memory space of 32 bits on most targets, There's only one memory address for each `int` in that array. I don't get what you mean or what confuses you.

Comment: ok but isn't ONE memory address only one byte? how is a 32 bit integer stored in a one byte storage area? that what is confusing me. how is `2000` stored in one memory address if the bit count overflows the memory address capacity? or is it not stored in such way?

Comment: @Josepha: a 32 bit integer gets stored in 4 bytes in memory. The type system and compiler keep track of those sizes for you, much of the time.

Comment: Memory addresses are 32 bits on 32-bit systems and 64 bits on 64-bit systems, not 8.  Addresses point to the first byte of potentially many.  The compiler knows how long it is based on type hints you provided (aka int, long, char[], etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a[] = {2000, 3000};
    printf("%p %p\n", &a[0], &a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the addresses of the elements of the array. For one run on my machine:

```
0x7ffc963400c0 0x7ffc963400c4
```

Notice they are 4 apart.  For an `int` array, each array index skips `sizeof(int)` memory addresses.  This is the same for all types of arrays, including arrays of `structs`. The array index identifies the *element*, not the *byte*.

Comment: ok one more question. according OsDev community, to write to the VGA buffer, we can write to memory address `0xB8000`. Now is this memory address a physical location on the memory and always will be at the same place? if so how big is it? I think my confusion is where I think a memory address is literally a little box on memory with a pre defined space

Comment: @Josepha When you are talking to the hardware through memory things get strange and the abstractions of C can lead you astray unless you have a clear understanding of what they are. Perhaps before screwing around with your hardware you should get familiar with C in userland first.

Comment: @Josepha as to your question regarding `0xB8000`, when you write to that, it could go anywhere. Memory mapping is an abstraction in hardware that makes it convenient to write close to the metal drivers in high level languages (C is high level in this context). One on architecture, writing to that address may write to some actual memory, or it could do dozens of other things and set various registers in hardware. You'll have to read the datasheets of the architecture to know the exact details.

Comment: so is `0xB8000` or any other memory address dynamically generated (lets say each time you restart your PC), or are they static? so if `0xB8000` writes to VGA in my case, will it always write to VGA on my pc no matter what?

Comment: @Josepha: if you want to talk directly to the hardware, you are going to need to consult the datasheet for your hardware. Only there will you get the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If each memory address can hold 1 byte (8 bits) of data

That’s not exactly right—it’s not that memory is partitioned into an array of boxes, each of which is 1 byte in size; it’s that 1 byte is the smallest *addressable* unit of memory. You can address memory in larger increments.

So if you have a pointer `char *p` containing some address such as `0x12345670`, that’s essentially just an offset into memory—it points to *the start of* a region that may comprise a single byte, or multiple bytes, such as an integer, array, or struct. (In fact it’s slightly more complicated, since what you see as a flat address space is actually *virtual memory* that’s mapped onto physical memory by the operating system kernel, but for the purposes of this explanation it doesn’t make a difference.)

A 32-bit integer with value `0xAABBCCDD` at address `p` simply occupies 4 bytes. These bytes may be arranged by the CPU in *big-endian* order, where the *most* significant bits are stored at the lowest address:

```
0x1234566F …
0x12345670 0xAA
0x12345671 0xBB
0x12345672 0xCC
0x12345673 0xDD
0x12345674 …
```

Or *little-endian*, where the *least* significant bits are stored at the lowest address:

```
0x1234566F …
0x12345670 0xDD
0x12345671 0xCC
0x12345672 0xBB
0x12345673 0xAA
0x12345674 …
```

A programming language like C abstracts over this somewhat to provide a convenient way to address objects of different sizes. Suppose there is some array of 32-bit integers `a`, and `p` is the address of the first element: `p = &a[0]`. In assembly, if you want to iterate over this array, you need to increment `p` by 4 each time to move it to the next integer:

```
&a[0] == p
&a[1] == p + 4
&a[2] == p + 8
&a[3] == p + 12
&a[4] == p + 16
…
```

In C, an expression like `p + 1` doesn’t just add a number of *bytes* to the value of `p`, it adds multiples of the object size, `sizeof(*p)`—so if `p` were typed as `uint32_t *p`, then `a[1]` would be at `p + 1`, `a[2]` at `p + 2`, and so on. Under the hood, `p + n` becomes something like `(char *)p + n * sizeof(*p)`.

> how does the CPU know when to stop reading bits of the memory addresses?

A primitive type like an integer is always a fixed size. When you write `*pi += 42` to add `42` to the contents of the 32-bit integer referred to by `pi`, that’s translated specifically to a 32-bit indirect-add instruction. A compound type like an array is just a series of values at addresses that are multiples of the object size—your program is responsible for only accessing within the bounds of the array. Higher-level languages insert automatic checks at runtime or compile-time to ensure *memory safety* by preventing invalid array accesses, among other things.

A dynamically allocated value like the result of `malloc` is just a region of memory that the allocator has given you control over, which in turn it obtains from the operating system. You can cast it to whatever type you want, such as an array of custom structures, as long as you only access within the region that you’ve been granted by the allocator.

Answer (score 1):

> If each memory address can hold 1 byte (8 bits) of data, then how come in some tutorials, it is mentioned that each array index is stored in one memory address? it's not possible since 2000 has 11 bits and needs at least 2 memory addresses to be stored.

Yes, each memory address can hold a byte.  However, often a block of memory is used to store things — this means using memory locations at consecutive memory addresses to store something larger than a byte.  An `int` is often 4 bytes long, for example; however, we can also store structs and objects that are even larger, not to mention arrays.

> My second question is, if it is stored in 2 (or more) memory addresses, how does the CPU know when to stop reading bits of the memory addresses? how does it know it has reached the end of the variable a above?

CPUs support multiple data types in that: they have instruction encodings for byte load, word load, and long word load, and a floating point load.  When it comes to larger items like a struct or an object, the compiler will generate multiple instructions (perhaps inline, perhaps in a loop, or maybe by calling a helper function in the library, i.e. something like `memmove` to copy a larger structure).

The CPU simply does what it is instructed to do by the code generated by the compiler.  The compiler chooses storage location & layout for variables.  After that, the compiler generates instructions to access those storage locations.

Note that all the CPU does is execute the (compiler or assembly) programmed instructions, which tell it how to operate on what data in tiny steps — the CPU doesn't know about the location & layout of variables per se, it just executes little instructions (really fast).

So, it is the compiler's job to generate coherent instruction streams for the CPU that are true to the meaning of the source code.  The definition of the language (e.g. the C standard) tells the compiler (or compiler writer) the meaning of language constructs found in the source code and this guides the translation to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

@Josepha said "ok but isn't ONE memory address only one byte?".

Not in C. The C language defines an abstract machine that is an overlay on the hardware architecture. The compiler arranges for things to appear as though you are running on the abstract machine, but emitting the necessary code for that specific architecture. There is no virtual or physical address space in C, only the pointers to objects and pointer to void, specified in the standard. When you work with a pointer in C, you have a token that represents a storage location, not a memory address. That pointer value, might actually have a bit pattern that matches that of an address bus bit pattern, but that's not relevant here.

When you have a pointer to an int, it points to an object that has sizeof(int), not sizeof physical memory cell.

Comment: So then in C, I can think of the `memory` as a huge empty space with no boundaries, and based on the type I have defined `int`, `char` etc. , the compiler will dedicate a chunk (dynamic size based on the type) of that space to me with the `memory address` pointing to the chunk. so a `1 byte memory address` is irrelevant and useless in C correct?

Comment: ok one more question. according OsDev community, to write to the VGA buffer, we can write to memory address `0xB8000`. Now is this memory address a physical location on the memory and always will be at the same place? if so how big is it? I think my confusion is where I think a memory address is literally a little box on memory with a pre defined space